# How to get associated column's value from selected item of combo-box in visual basic 2013?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, combobox

I am working with Visual Basic 2013 and sqlite. My table structure is like -

- topic_id
- topic_name
- subject_id
- subject_name
- chapter_no

I am importing this table into combo box as -

```
 Dim con As SQLiteConnection
 Dim sql As String
 Dim da As SQLiteDataAdapter
 Dim ds As New DataSet
 Dim cmd As New SQLiteCommand

 con = New SQLiteConnection("Data Source = test.db;Version=3;")
 con.Open()
 sql = "SELECT * FROM med_topics"
 da = New SQLiteDataAdapter(sql, con)
 da.Fill(ds, "TopicsList")
 con.close()
 cboTopicsList.DisplayMember = "Topic_Name"
 cboTopicsList.ValueMember = "Topic_Id"
 cboTopicsList.DataSource = ds.Tables("TopicsList")
```

I want to use tables other column's value (but don't want them to display in combo box) viz. "subject_id, subject_name, chapter_no".
**I know these values are imported in `TopicsList`, but I don't know, how to get the corresponding value of the selected item.** I am stuck here.

Comment: Try on SelectedIndexChanget ComboBox Event,  to get the row from TopicList with Topic_ID

Answer (score 0):

A `ComboBox` populate its object collection (the *Items* property) with [DataRowView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowview(v=vs.110).aspx) objects when bound to a `DataTable`. This is because the `DataTable` class implements [IListSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.ilistsource(v=vs.110).aspx) which the `ComboBox` looks for. It returns a [DataView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview(v=vs.110).aspx), the [DefaultView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.defaultview(v=vs.110).aspx) of the table.

```
Private Sub cboTopicsList_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cboTopicsList.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim rowView As DataRowView = TryCast(cboTopicsList.SelectedItem, DataRowView)
    If (Not rowView Is Nothing) Then
        Dim row As DataRow = rowView.Row
        Dim subjectName As String = DirectCast(row.Item("subject_name"), String)
        '...
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks. but due to `DirectCast` all the rows are now showing "System.Data.DataRowView", if I use DirectCast with anything other than `Topic_Name` (i.e. Subject_Name, Chapter_No etc). I confirm that my column names are correct. But, somehow they are not displaying.